# Fixed position of button in the middle of fixed page

Tags: css, position, margin, fixed

my page has one big div with fixed width, like this:

```
#index_body{
  width: 1010px;
  background-image: url('images/main_bg_dark.png'); 
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #000000;
}
```

I want to add button (20x20px) on the right side of page (vertically in the middle) - still next to index_body.

So the button has code, like this:

```
#butt {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: url('images/scrollUp.png');
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:WHAT SHOULD BE HERE??
}
```

Because it depends on actual resolution. My index_body is always centered. if I change resolution my button is moved to the left-right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it should be just like this:

```
#butt {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: url('images/scrollUp.png');
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: 1010px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `left` or `right` position, make sure the button element is inside the index element and then use a margin.

`margin: 0px 0px 0px 1010px;`

Here is a tested and working version with your code - http://lukewakeford.co.uk/testsite/blackbutton/

Answer (score 0):

```
#butt {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: url('images/scrollUp.png');
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;

  right: 10%;
}
```

The 10% is an example, change to a percentage that looks good, and it should be responsive to screen resolution.

On the other hand, why would you want a fixed element INSIDE a fixed container? just make it absolute and float it to the right with a margin.

Comment: This 10% is for nothing. Because with changing resolution it moves... <= what is my problem.... And I can't do it absolute, because my **index_body** div has big height. I just want let this **#butt** on the same position during scrolling the page